# How to get the same post to not show twice when being pulled with a counter

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, counter

So I have this as the post counter

```
    <?php 
        if ( $postcounter%6== 0 ) 
        include( locate_template( '/my-include.php', false, false ) ); 
    ?>
<?php
endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata();
endif; 
//resets the hotel counter to zero so it can show another featured article after the next 6 hotels. 
$postcounter = 0;
?>
```

I am pulling the posts with an include that has this for the loop

```
<?php 
 $offset = rand(1, 100);
 $args = array( 
 'orderby' => 'rand',
 'post_type' => 'blog',
 'posts_per_page'=>1,
 'meta_query' => array(
 array(
  'key' => 'status',
  'value'    => 'featured'
  )
  ), 
  'tax_query' => array(
 array(
'taxonomy' => 'content',
'field'    => 'slug',
'terms'    => 'my-category'
 )
 )
 );

 $pull_articles = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

This does currently work but it seems to show the same post a lot. Is there a way to make sure it never shows the same post? Like a prevention on duplicate posts even though I am using a counter and its posting per every 6th post?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little hacky, but you could save the ids for the posts you've returned in an array and pass those to wp's post__not_in argument.